# Angular ag-Grid: how to autogenerate default template for cell but with different name of field?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have ag-grid when a lot of columns have specific templates. But some of data that I put into table are nothing more than just text until now.. I want to put something more for default case:

```
<ng-template #defaultRecord let-record>
  ADDITIONAL THINGS HERE
  <!-- CHOOSEN FIELD HERE -->
</ng-template>
```

So I have method for autogenerating columns:

```
  private generateColumn(headerNameKey: string, colId: string, ngTemplate: TemplateRef<any>, filter = true, sortable = true, field?: string) {
  const headerName = headerNameKey ? this.translateService.instant(headerNameKey) : '';
  return {
  headerName,
  field,
  sortable,
  filter,
  colId,
  cellRendererFramework: CellRendererComponent,
  cellRendererParams: {
    ngTemplate
  }
};
}
```

And I don't know how to use unspecified field in template. For example I get from api data when field is called "XYZ", how to make display it in my default template?

In this case:

```
<ng-template #defaultRecord let-record>
  ADDITIONAL THINGS HERE
  <span> Value of XYZ param</span>
</ng-template>
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

EDIT 1:

Custom CellRenderer Component:

```
export class CellRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  template: TemplateRef<any>;
  templateContext: { $implicit: any, params: ICellRendererParams };

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams) {
    this.template = params['ngTemplate'];
    this.refresh(params);
  }

  refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
    this.templateContext = {
      $implicit: params.data,
      params
   };
    return true;
  }
}
```

And how params in `agInit` method looks:
[image]

And as You can see in the picture, in the template I want to display value of `Fields.Date` param that is defined field. How I suppose to use it in the template above?

Comment: Very unique question on Ag-grid I have ever seen here, also I haven't used auto generating columns before. I am watching the answers..

Comment: I may not be understanding correctly. But it looks like you have a custom cell renderer component in which the html has a template inside of it. The `agInit` function in the cell renderer passes in the column and row objects, so you can get the data: `row[colDef.field]`.

Comment: @MattNienow i just edited my question and put there custom cellrenderer component. You mean that I have to add other field like `chosenField: any` and then assing something to this in `agInit` function? `this.chosenField = params['field]` and the field from array is that param that I put in my `generateColumn` method in property `cellRendererParams`?

Comment: Yes, something like that should work. Also, there should be a `value` attribute on the params object, which should just contain the value automatically.

Comment: @MattNienow but how can I call it in the template? When I have `let-record` in the `ng-template` the record is that what is in the `data` from params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly what you want to do.
Then here is one way.

You add context parameter to the template context.

```
<ng-template #defaultRecord let-record let-value="value">
    ADDITIONAL THINGS HERE
    <span> {{value}} </span>
</ng-template>
```

And you calculate this value in renderer component.

```
refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
    const valuePath = params.colDef.field;
    const value = _.get(params.data, valuePath); // using lodash
    this.templateContext = {
        $implicit: params.data,
        params,
        value
    };
    return true;
}
```

I am using lodash function, but you can use other library or write simple method to get value from the object using its path.